# Do All Google Oauth 2.0 Client need verification?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

If I plan to use the following scope:

https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file

Does Google need to verify my consent screen?

What does application type public mean? I'm assuming that if it is not accessible to everyone than it is not public.

Does sensitive scope always mean full access?

Comment: "Does sensitive scope always mean full access?" - Nope, some sensitive scopes are readonly, such as `../auth/contacts.readonly`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, if you use a sensitive scope and trigger the Google OAuth authorization flow, you should see an [unverified app screen](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en) that indicates that you need to apply for app verification.

You do not need to request a review if one of the following is true:

- Your app is an enterprise application built only for your enterprise users. You should make sure your Google Cloud Project is associated with your [cloud organization](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/cloud-platform-resource-hierarchy#organizations)
- You are building an app just for yourself or a few users. See the 'OAuth user quotas' section [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7454865?hl=en).

Comment: Where is the list of the sensitive scopes? This answer does not answer the question of whether drive.file is a sensitive scope or not.

Answer (score 2):

**Verification is required if:**

- Your application type is public, and
- You add a sensitive scope

[image: See this image for more details]

Comment: Perhaps you could add an explanation of what this adds to the already accepted answer.